# how to call a jquery function from html file in js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I don't know how to call my jQuery function from my HTML file.

This function was in the HTML file at the beginning. I moved it in to a JS file and would like to call it from this as the code looks cleaner when I have different files for the different languages.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    autoclose: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    orientation: "button"
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    autoclose: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    orientation: "button"
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendar.js"></script>
<div onclick="datumEins()" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Startdatum</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker'>

            > i think the calling must be putted in the input tag

            <input type='text' id="datum1" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--ENDDATUM-->
<div onclick="datumZwei" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Enddatum</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker2'>

            > i think the calling must be putted in the input tag

            <input type='text' id="datum2" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to include `jQuery.js` before bootstrap, and you've not included the library which adds the datepicker control.

Comment: you mean like this:
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script >
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
       format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
       autoclose: true,
       todayHighlight: true,
       showOtherMonths: true,
       selectOtherMonths: true,
       autoclose: true,
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true,
       orientation: "button"
    });
});

Comment: No, jquery.js needs to come first in the references. Also `datepicker()` is not a standard jQuery method, so you need to add a reference to whatever library includes it